# Why is list of names no more capable of expressing a proposition?

Tags: set-theory

From the Open Logic Project book 2.2, Philosophical reflections (Set theory):

Third: when we “identify” relations with sets, we said that we would allow ourselves to write Rxy for ⟨x, y⟩ ∈ R. This is fine, provided that the membership relation, “∈”, is treated as a predicate. But if we think that “∈” stands for a certain kind of set, then the expression “⟨x, y⟩ ∈ R” just consists of three singular terms which stand for sets: “⟨x, y⟩”, “∈”, and “R”. And such a list of names is no more capable of expressing a proposition than the nonsense string: “the cup penholder the table”. Again, even if some relations can be treated as sets, the relation of set-membership must be a special case. (This rolls together a simple version of Frege’s concept horse paradox, and a famous objection that Wittgenstein once raised against Russell.)

I don't understand the paragraph. Why is the list of names no more capable of expressing a proposition? What are Frege's concept horse paradox and Wittgenstein's objection, and how are they related to all this?

Comment: A proposition (meaningful sentence) needs a verb: "Jhon is running", "Mark loves Mary". That's all... no deep philosophical mistery.

Comment: Thus, in set theory where everything is a set, we still need a "verb": the "in" relation.

Comment: See the answer to [the same post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4805302/why-is-list-of-names-no-more-capable-of-expressing-a-proposition) in MSE.

Answer (score 0):

In some natural languages, nouns can be used as verbs, regardless of whether the words are synonymous. In order to form a meaningful sentence in formal logic, it is necessary to define or synthesize semantic signs. This is possible in classical logic.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that this view is trying to *define* all relations as sets. Since ∈ represents a relation between sets and their members, this means that ∈ is really just a set of pairs. But if ∈ is just a set of pairs, how do we use it to say that an object is a member of a set? We need a relation to say that, let's call the relation ∈2. So now, if we have an element x and a set S, instead of saying x ∈ S we say the pair (x,S) is in ∈, or (∈) to avoid confusion: (x,S) ∈2 (∈). But ∈2 is just a set of pairs. I think you can see how this is going to lead to a problem.

Answer (score 0):

Aristotle defines a proposition as a sentence that affirms or denies a predicate of some subject through a copula like "is" or "are". For example given the name Paris a proposition about it would be "Paris is French".